# Comparing "long" and "Long"

Tags: java, equals, primitive, autoboxing

I want to compare a `long` value (primitive type) with another `Long` value (wrapper type):

```
long x = 5;
Long y = 5L;

// version 1: only safe, if x is a primitive type
var isEqual = x == y;

// version 2: y needs to be converted to its primitive type
var isEqual = x == y.longValue();

// version 3: using Object.equals(), x will be converted to its wrapper type
var isEqual = Objects.equals(x, y);
```

The question is:
Is there any benefit in using **version 2** instead of **version 3**?

Comment: They are all more or less identical. In particular V1 and V2 are the same after compilation (check their bytecode). Be careful with V1 and V2 who will **both** throw a NPE if `y` is `null`. V3 will box `x` to `Long` and do a `Long` vs `Long` comparison, hence support `null` correctly and wont throw.

Comment: Imagine, x is also a LONG (and not a long), then version 1 would not be correct, because `Long x = 200L;
Long y = 200L; var isEqual = x == y;` returned false.

Comment: Well, yeah. But you specifically made `x` a `long`. And `long == Long` leads to unwrapping conversion to get `long == long`, which the compiler does by calling `longValue()`. So V1 and V2 are identical after compilation (with the types you have in your question).

Comment: As a minor side note, comparing `Long == Long` (you did not do this here, but I am still noting it) can lead to undesired results since `Long` instances are not cached for the full range.

Comment: @nimo23, @Zabuzard: I think that you are both right! Zabuzard is right that in this case it is perfectly safe to compare with `==`. But I think nimo23 is right in that even if it is safe, it is a bit hard to understand and easy to make mistakes when using `==` with boxes. So it's better to avoid it altogether!

Comment: Side note: In Project Valhalla the Java developers are working on a way to unify boxes with primitives. This will, among other things, make comparitions using `==` between boxes safe. See [here](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/valhalla-spec-experts/2021-November/001617.html) for example.

Comment: Thanks. I made some corrections.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The advantage of `Objects.equals(x, y)` is that it covers null cases. The first two would throw a NPE if the `Long` variable is null.

On the other hand, `Objects.equals(x, y)` would autobox the `long` (primitive) argument, hence creating an object. But normally this shouldn't be a concern.

So: just `Objects.equals()` because the comparison involves a wrapper object and to keep the code simple and readable, otherwise just check for nullability before comparing primitives with `Long.longValue()`.